# check if list item has more than 1 direct span child in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I check if a list item has **more than 1 direct span child element** in jquery?
I have something now like:

```
if ( $('li:has(span)') ) {
   alert ('has span');
}
```

That will alert already when there's one span child, and also if there are nested li's who themselves have one or more span child elements.

Comment: Do you mean *equal or greater than 1*?

Comment: equal or greater than 2

Comment: `$('li').filter(function(){return $(this).children('span').length > 1})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will alert if there is 2 or more child `span` elements.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if($('> span',this).length >= 2)
    {
       alert('has span');
    }
});
```

or using A. Wolff filter answer.

```
$('li').filter(function(){return $('> span',this).length > 1;});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tzbJ/

Comment: i'd use filter and here you are not checking for direct descendants but all: $(this).children('span').length  i mean

Comment: @A.Wolff ah true. missed that.

Comment: Why not simply `$('li > span').length`?

Comment: That's ok even $('> *',context) syntax was deprecated in the past (looks like no more DOC about it) and for sure still works +1

Comment: @h2ooooooo we need to keep context on element, not all LIs

Comment: @A.Wolff could get the same results by starting with `li > span`

Comment: @h2ooooooo `$(...)` returns a set of all matches. If there are two or mote `li` tags that have a single `span` the results will be `>1`

Comment: Never mind my last reply. I hadn't thought of `<li><span></span></li><li><span></span></li>`. @MathewFoscarini Yeah - I just realized. Friday, right? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('li > span:eq(1)').length ) {
   alert ('has span');
}
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjDHE/)

Comment: This adds all the spans of all li's

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('li > span:eq(0)').length > 0 ) {
   alert ('has span');
}
```